# Why does time spent in OnPaint event seem to depend upon refresh rate?

Tags: c#, paintevent

I am working with C# and WinForms and I am drawing some stuff in a user control. The content of each frame is calculated inside `OnPaint` event, being triggered by a `Control.Invalidate()` call. This call occurs every few milliseconds, depending on the `Timer.Interval` property. Then, I am measuring how long it takes to render the frame and displaying the moving averaged value.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
void Init() {
    period = 40;
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(period);
    timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerTick);
    timer.Start();
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    busy = false;
    overlap = 0;
}

void TimerTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    if ( !busy )
        this.renderScene.Invalidate();
    else
        overlap++;
}

void RenderScenePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    busy = true;
    long start = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100, 100, 10, 10);
    }
    long stop = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    calculator.Push((int)(stop - start));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(calculator.Average().ToString() + " ms (" + overlap.ToString() + ")", Constants.FONT_DEFAULT, Constants.ACTIVE_BRUSH, 0, 0);
    busy = false;
}
```

The thing is I am dealing with a counterintuitive situation:

- if I set `period` to 40 (25 FPS), the mean duration to render each frame is 15 ms on my computer
- if I set `period` to 10 (100 FPS), the mean duration *drops* to 4 ms (confirmed by a lower CPU usage in task manager)
- if I set `period` to 100 (10 FPS), the mean duration *increases* to 20 ms (confirmed by a higher CPU usage in task manager)

Question: how can this be possible? It seems like a higher frame rate leads to a lower CPU usage!

**EDIT** - A few points based on the comments and feedbacks I have received so far:

1. Sample project created using SharpDevelop can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bH0P_-U2IsnAQtTm6FY2n3adeaeBdxdC/view?usp=sharing). It is set up to compile against .NET Framework 4.0 but I tried various versions and this does not change the measurements.
2. Yes, the `for` loop could be optimized into one single line as I am always drawing the same ellipse. But the point is to generate CPU calculation. Drawing different shapes at different locations does not change the measurements.
3. `overlap` is always 0 so I know that events are not overlapping in the sense that no event is raised before the previous one has completed.
4. I know `Timers` are not accurate, but this is unrelated to my question. Actually I am not interested at which rate each frame is being drawn, I am considering the amount of time required to draw one. And this duration I am measuring, I am doing it with a Stopwatch, whose accuracy is beyond questionable (approximately 1 nanosecond according to MSDN).
5. I also tried keeping the timer interval constant, and triggering the `OnPaint` event only 1 time over X instead. This leads to the same results and conclusion.

To sum up, I am just trying to understand why the time spent to paint a frame (this is exactly what I am measuring with the stopwatch) depends upon the timer interval (which imho should be unrelated).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216117/discussion-on-question-by-couitchy-why-does-time-spent-in-onpaint-event-seem-to).

Answer (score 0):

Your test probably get context switched, that's why you get a interval between 15~20ms in lower fps.

For cpu usage, 100 fps > 25 fps > 10 fps. 
Test is inconsistent because you have different loading by the setting of timer.
If timer interval is smaller, its priority might be somewhat higher and not getting context switch.

This is not accurate description but you might get the point.

Do some test by following, you might get a consistent result.

1. Try to fix your test timer interval but change behavior by counting tick in program itself. You might found different result.
2. Change timer from System.Timers.Timer to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and remove `Invoke`

Edit: Just found your code is drawing fixed ellipse.

```
void RenderScenePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    long start = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100, 100, 10, 10);
    }
    long stop = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    calculator.Push((int)(stop - start));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(calculator.Average().ToString() + " ms",     Constants.FONT_DEFAULT, Constants.ACTIVE_BRUSH, 0, 0);
}
```

Might be optimized to following code, which is calculating single line with context switch time.

```
void RenderScenePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    long start = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100, 100, 10, 10); //It is JUST a line
    long stop = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    calculator.Push((int)(stop - start));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(calculator.Average().ToString() + " ms", Constants.FONT_DEFAULT, Constants.ACTIVE_BRUSH, 0, 0);
}
```

You should change it to

```
void RenderScenePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    long start = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100 +i, 100, 10, 10);
    }
    long stop = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    calculator.Push((int)(stop - start));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(calculator.Average().ToString() + " ms", Constants.FONT_DEFAULT, Constants.ACTIVE_BRUSH, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried to keep the timer interval constant (10 ms), while invalidating the control only 1 time over X. The problem remains the same: if X is 4, the time spent in OnPaint is greater than when X is 1.

Comment: I edit my answer, just found your draw test might be optimized into single line. Which is literally testing context switch.